# Можете обяснить логику этого кода?

Tags: javascript, массивы, математика

```js
let list = [-2,56,342,-6,3456,345,27,34,86,234,6865,3,4,5,647,];
function find(arr) {
    let max = -Infinity;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
console.log(find(list));
```

`-Infinity` это минусавой бесканечность я этого понял, Но на л написано что если  `-Infinity` больше  `arr[i]` то мах равно `arr[i]` . В масиве даже 3 больше. Почемы выводится именно самое большое число?

Comment: Потому что это стандартный алгоритм для поиска максимального значения в массиве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-infinity` это минимально возможное число. Цикл for проходит по всем элементам массива и сравнивает эти элементы с максимальным. То есть на первом проходе он сравнит `-2` и `-infinity` и занесет в переменную `max` `-2`. На втором проходе он сравнит `56` и `-2`, `56` занесет в переменную. Таким образом, к концу цикла в переменной `max` окажется максимальное значение из массива (или `-infinity`, если массив пустой).